# Boostrap active item does not work properly

Tags: html, django, django-models, bootstrap-4, django-templates

I'm trying to create a tab-pane card in which I could choose to see two different graph: `revenue-chart` and `sales-chart`.
But I have a problem with the `active` feature. If I set my code in the followig manner:

```
<ul class="nav nav-pills ml-auto">
        <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link active" href="#revenue-chart" data-toggle="tab">Storico</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link" href="#sales-chart" data-toggle="tab">Budget</a>
        </li>
    </ul>
    </div>
    </div><!-- /.card-header -->
    <div class="card-body">
        <div class="tab-content p-0">
            <!-- Morris chart - Sales -->
            <div class="chart tab-pane active" id="revenue-chart"
            style="position: relative; height: 300px;">
            <canvas class=" w-100 " id="revenue-chart-canvas"  height="300" style="height: 300px;"></canvas>
        </div>
        <div class="chart tab-pane " id="sales-chart"
        style="position: relative; height: 300px;">
        <canvas class=" w-100 " id="sales-chart-canvas" height="300" style="height: 300px;"></canvas>
    </div>
```

it show me only the first graph. And If I try to select the second graph does not appear it. How could fix my problem?

Comment: refer to https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.5/components/navs/#javascript-behavior, it's a working demo, i guess you are missing `show` class

Comment: okey thanks but I don't understand where I have to put this class